# A photo viewing/organising software for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, images

I've just been on holiday, and I took a lot of photos.

I need a software to view these photos on my PC, and I want to be able browse through the photos quickly, delete them with a single click (undoable click ideal), as well as some how mark some of them so I can make a 'best of' album.

Answer (score 5):

Moderator's update: [Like most Google products](https://killedbygoogle.com), Google no longer supports Picasa.

---

I still use [Picasa](https://picasa.google.com/) for this kind of management.

You can:

- scroll through all your photos, grouped by directory;
- add photos to favorites (star them) or add them to custom albums;
- delete photos (either from the Picasa view or from the disk altogether).

Additional features worth of note:

- Face detection (quite efficient at recognizing similarities once you've begun naming them).
- Basic photo amelioration (most of which are stored as settings, not altering your picture; anti-red eye *will* alter your file; you have auto-contrast, auto-color, feeling lucky, ...).

A drawback: as Google tries to push Google Photos, you will have to face a pop-up after each update, proposing you to back up your photos on Google (I hate being sollicitated with bundled service/software if it is not my own choice).

Comment: I don't like Picassa for the reasons you listed. Also - because I otherwise don't use it, it's awkward when old photos pop up on my phone or whatever.

Comment: You only need to _not_ accept online backup (which I did). As for the phone, Google tends to tightly integrate its product in Android and it does require some settings and knowledge to avoid the photos appearing there (what you sent via Hangouts is available in G Photos, for instance). But the photos from my computer never leaked to my G account or my phone. Photos on Android only shows me G+ or Hangouts posts, and I can remove them when I need to. I understand the awkwardness though (a friend went through my pics recently and dug out oldies but not goodies).

Answer (score 5):

I use [Windows Photo Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-live/photo-gallery). It is included as standard with some versions of Windows, or available to download free of charge as part of Windows Essentials. The latest version is Windows Photo Gallery 2012.

It allows you to browse through your photos easily.

There are several ways for marking photos you are interested in:

- Add a descriptive tag
- Flagging particular photos
- Add a star rating, i.e. 1 to 5

Then you can search by any of these, to find your best photos. Note the tag and ratings are stored within the photo files. So you can also search for them using Windows Explorer.

You can easily delete photos, though it's not quite single click - you have to click delete, then answer "Yes" to the prompt. This just moves the photo to the Recycle Bin, so it can be restored from there in the usual way.