# Photo preview and quick deletion tool for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, image-viewer

I have a folder containing ~900 jpeg pictures which I would like to heavily tidy out, i.e. delete most of them. I am looking for a tool displaying each picture one by one and allowing me to delete it by a simple keyboard shortcut (e.g. <kbd>Del</kbd>).
Similar apps in the same spirit exist for Android, e.g. [Photo Delete App. Delete Photo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.poofit.photodelete&hl=de).

#### Requirements

- Runs on Windows 10
  (can also be a Windows 10 UWP app if possible)
- Goes through all pictures one by one from a specified folder
- Allows me to quickly delete the previewed picture, e.g. by pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>.
- Provides an undo feature for the most recent deleted pictures.
  This differentiates this question from "[A photo viewing/organising software for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20320/a-photo-viewing-organising-software-for-windows)". The [suggested Windows Photo Gallery](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/20335/583) does not offer an undo feature and searching the recycle bin, which probably contains a lot of other files, requires excessive effort.
- Supported picture formats: at least JPEG.

#### Nice to have

- Favorite some pictures, so that they are protected in another pass through a folder's pictures.
- Allows customization of where deleted pictures will be stored: in the recycle bin or in a custom folder.
- Other picture or even document formats such as GIF, PNG, TIFF, PDF.
- Support for video files

Price: I am open for gratis as well as low-cost (~0-20€) tools.